# A question about almost stationary orbits

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, orbitals, space-travel

For an orbit around the earth with period equal to a sidereal day with eccentricity $e=0$ and inclination $i=0$, the path on earth would be a single point on the equator. I have done some simulations that suggests that if $e>0$ and $i>0$ the path would take the form of the figure '8'. If $e\gg 0$ one loop in the figure would be less than the other and greater $i$ gives a taller '8'.

My question is: what would the figure be if $e=0$ and $i=90^{°}$?

Comment: Intuitively, a large circle, but hopefully someone can do the math. See the Analemma Tower project: https://www.dezeen.com/2017/03/23/supertall-hanging-skyscraper-asteroid-clouds-architecture-office-concept-analemma-tower/